Can you use "biject" as a verb?
Is it normal/conventional to say "We wish to biject set A with set B" in order to express our intention of finding a bijection between A and B? Or does this read as unusual?
Outside of whether this is a common usage of "biject" or not, is it immediately clear what the sentence "We wish to biject set A with set B" is intended to convey, or might this be misinterpreted somehow by a math student / mathematician?

I think it’s clear, but is there any reason to say that instead of “we wish to find a bijection between $A$ and $B$”? What advantage does it have? Slightly fewer words?

There's other verbs already like "maps" I think and things you old use instead besides transforming bijection into a verb.

@Malady Thanks for the response! In the sentence I'm writing, "set A" and "set B" take many many words to name/identify (they are preceded by many mathematical adjectives), and the slight reduction in the number of words used to convey our intention to find a bijection actually makes the overall sentence much more readable imo.

@qatest hmmmm, maybe "We wish to bijectively map A into B" is better then? It's important in this case for me to convey that the mapping is specifically a bijection.

Brevity isn't nearly as important as clarity...I'd go ahead and spend the extra couple of words.

Any word can be verbed, but overdoing it weirds the language.

I like this verb.  Bijection sounds very archaic

@DanielDonnelly, I reject your desire to inject biject into the lexicon. I conject that it will not deject you.

Can you?  Sure.  Language is malleable, and it can change over time.  If you use "to biject" as a verb often enough, and convince other people to do the same, it will enter the lexicon as a perfectly cromulent word.  Should you?  Well, there's the rub...

Yes. This is fine and I have routinely heard it spoken and seen it written. I don't see any ambiguity to it and have never thought twice about it being somehow non-standard. You can also say "inject", though "surject" is perhaps less usual

I'm a use this verb :)  @PaulTanenbaum your over-use of such verbs can be analogously replicated using nouns.

@DanielDonnelly, there is not a surprise production information transmission from you to me.

Even though I've never encountered "biject", I sure did see often (and use myself) "surject onto..." or "inject into" referring to surjections respectively injections but only if it  is clear from the context.

It should be OK. One reason is that the meaning is immediately clear. The other reason is that it is used in several research papers, indicating that it is a common phrase. Here is a selection of examples.
From Forster's Stratification mod n and the Cylindrical Theory of Types:

We have to biject the set of points below the line
with the set of points above the line in a way that ...

From Schwede's Global algebraic K-theory:

Since every countably infinite set bijects with the set $\omega$ ...

From Strickland's Products of MU-modules:

We see from Lemma 4.2 that ring maps from $A_i$ to $B$ biject with systems of ring maps $g_j : R/x_j \to B$ ...

From Gossow's Lyndon-like cyclic sieving and Gauss congruence:

We prove that both sets biject with pairs ...

Even other forms are possible. From Arathoon's A bijection between the adjoint and coadjoint orbits of a semidirect product:

The orbits equal to the origin are both bijected with each other.

See here for a related discussion about "induct".

I'm not sure finding 3 examples, all in papers and only one apparently published, counts as "common." "Induct" is already a verb outside mathematics, although with an admittedly very different meaning. I don't think it is awful to use "biject" this way, but this,is a stronger statement of support for it than I would give.

@ThomasAndrews There are plenty of other papers out there with this wording, according to a quick Google Scholar search; these are 3 examples, but they're not the only ones.

Completely agreed with this answer — it’s a bit jargony, but it’s pretty well-established and certainly not wrong or unclear.  Also worth noting that while the examples given here are all intransitive, with the set/structure as the grammatical subject (“the set $X$ bijects with the set $Y$”), OP’s transitive usage with the mathematician as subject (“we can biject $X$ with $Y$”) also sounds quite natural to me, analogously to standard transitive pairs like “the bell rang”/“I rang the bell”; I’ll try to find an example.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine True. I have added another example with "we have to biject...". I put it as the first one since it is very close to the exact phrase the OP suggested.

"... know that ring maps A→B biject with ..." is one of those phrases where you can be led the wrong way, since maps might be initially read as a verb until you see biject.

@Henry Not really in this context. I have updated (and fixed) the quote to give more context. It's quite clear then.
